# Calculate max value

Tags: equation-solving

## Update

Using

```
Manipulate[Plot[{(LogIntegral[x])^(1/2), 
(((x*E^s)/Log[x*E^s]) ((((Log[Log[x*E^s]])^(w - 1))/((w - 1)!))))/
RiemannR[x]}, {x, 2, 5000}, PlotStyle -> {Blue,Red}, ImageSize -> 700], 
{w, 33.34, 40, 0.01}, {s, 43.2, 50, 0.01}]
```

to play with the plot

[image]

I am trying to find the max values of `w` and `s` ***where the $y$-value of the red curve is at no point greater in value that of the blue curve (for any $x$)***. Is there a better way of doing this?

(I have started `w` and `s` at a reasonable estimate, but when values become much higher than $1000$, manipulation is not really feasible.)

N.B. My best guess so far at the relationship between `s` and `w` is `s=[N[Log[((w/5) + 1)!]]`, but this is clearly way off.

## Original question

Which approach would be the best to take in order to calculate the max value of $a$, where $a\log(x+1)$ at no point exceeds $\sqrt{x}$?

```
Plot[{a Log[x + 1], Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

I have tried using `Manipulate` to get a rough guess, but I am really searching for a more accurate approach.

Comment: Try `Manipulate[
 Plot[{a Log[x + 1], Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 100}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}], {a, 1, 10}]`

Comment: Yes - I have done - that is how I got this :/ - It is not exact though & relies on trial & error

Comment: I have changed the post accordingly.

Comment: Graphs always intersect since near zero `Log` increases faster than `Sqrt`, but for larger `x` `Sqrt` exceeds `Log`. You should play e.g. with `Series[#, {x, 0, 5}] & /@ {Log[x + 1], Sqrt[x]}` or with `Manipulate[
 Plot[{a Log[x + 1], Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, b}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 0.5, 100}]`.

Comment: Thanks for the `Series` suggestion- looks promising :)

Comment: Regarding that the issue might be more involved for generic functions this question doesn't address underlying problem with sufficient generality.

Comment: Could you provide any suggestions as to how the question might be improved, please?

Comment: The above is clearly a simple example of a more complex problem. But the essence of the question remains the same.

Comment: Starting with your initial functions (involving `RiemannR`) might be appropriate.

Comment: If `s -> Infinity` at a faster rate than `s -> Infinity`, it is possible for the red curve to meet the blue curve at y > 0. I am not sure what this relationship between `s` and `w` is though, as I said in the post above.

Comment: eg - Try `w = 55.15, s = 88`.

Comment: Sorry, for above comment, read   
If `s -> Infinity` at a faster rate than `w -> Infinity`

Comment: .... See emboldened text in post.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Since you've edited this question another time you should have to add the special-functions tag.

Comment: @Artes Another time? Have I done it more than once? What is the special functions tag? (I'm relatively new to this forum.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Sorry, you've eddited it only once. See [special-functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-functions).

Comment: @Artes I see. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is an answer to the original question)

After playing a bit with

```
f[x_,a_]:=Sqrt[x] - a Log[1 + x];
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, a], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-.2, 1/2}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

you see you want both f and its derivative wrt x == 0. However, trying

```
Solve[Sqrt[x] - a Log[1 + x] == 0 && D[Sqrt[x] - a Log[1 + x], x] == 0, {x, a}]
```

does not work ("*This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve*"). Still, solving twice for "a" yields

```
a1 = a /. Solve[Sqrt[x] - a Log[1 + x] == 0, {a}] // First
a2 = a /. Solve[D[Sqrt[x] - a Log[1 + x], x] == 0, {a}] // First
```

with output

```
Sqrt[x]/Log[1 + x]
(1 + x)/(2 Sqrt[x])
```

The x is

```
xx = Solve[a1 == a2, {x}][[1, 1]] // N (* remove "//N" if you like *)
```

output :

```
x -> 3.92155
```

and a is

```
a1 /. xx
```

output :

```
1.24263
```

ps. *I would very much like to know why the first attempt to solve for both $x$ and $a$ does not work while doing it step by step does. Any suggestion ?*